# Changing the value on an existing session variable on an onclick event in javascript while staying on the same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, events, jstl

I want to update the value of a session attribute when a button is clicked on a page without using a form and redirecting to another page.

I've looked at JSTL and scriptlets but because these occur on the server end, they already happen before the button is clicked.

I have looked into AJAX but I am not entirely sure how the whole process works.

Any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

Something that can be incorporated into:

```js
function myFunction()
{
    //setAttribute("session_variable_name", "newvalue")
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Change Variable</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ajax is the way to go:

Jquery ajax:

```
var request = $.ajax({
  url: "/changesession.jsp", 
  type: "POST",
  data: ["newSessionValue"=>'newSessionValue'],
});

request.done(function( msg ) {
  alert('suceess changed');
});


request.fail(function(msg)) {
   alert('failed ajax')
});
```

And in your `changesession.jsp`

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
String newValue= ${param.newSessionValue};
setAttribute("session_variable_name", "newvalue");
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot! One question though wouldn't the following be in the servlet rather that the jsp:  
`HttpSession session = request.getSession();
String newValue= ${param.newSessionValue};
setAttribute("session_variable_name", "newvalue");`

Comment: it can be in either sevlet or jsp.. depends on what you want to acheieve after it. If you put that in a servelet then make sure to chage the URL to point to that particular servlet.

Answer (score -1):

PHP side code `// the_php_file_that_change_your_session.php`

```
<?php 
    if( isset($_POST["sessionVarName"]) && isset($_POST["sessionVarValue"]) ) 
    {
        $_SESSION[$_POST["sessionVarName"]] = $_POST["sessionVarValue"] ;
    }
    exit();
?>
```

Javascript side code

```
function myFunction()
{
    $.post("the_php_file_that_change_your_session.php",{sessionVarName:sessionVarName_Value,sessionVarValue:sessionVarValue},function()
    {
        // do what you want after the Session variable is changed
    });
}
```

Comment: this isn't a php issue. it's to do with jsp

Comment: It's an Ajax issue . i used php as an exemple ,but he can change it to any other server language

Comment: then probably you should remove `PHP side code` and replace it with general `serverside abstraction`